# how debug nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Добрый день.
Сегодня пришлось по работе поставить nginx и нем у меня должен крутиться зродовенный проект из разными доменами и другими прелестями. Так как в тему nginx долго времени нет вглублятся подскажите пожалуйста как я могу "дебажить" конфиг чтобы понять куда "ходит" сервак а куда нет. У меня есть пример конфига из такого проекта и у меня он пока не "заводится".
**Вопрос** как можно дебажить через логи прописывая что то в конфигах?

PS: У меня Ubuntu 16, php5.6-fpm, nginx version: nginx/1.10.0

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/debugging_log.html

Comment: Спасибо ознакамливаюсь

Comment: Дебажат дебаггером: gdb nginx